# How to use vue3/vue router correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

I had some problems trying out the vue3.

router is my custom.

```
import router from './router'
```

when i write

```
createApp(App).use(Antd,VueAxios,axios,qs,router).mount('#app')
```

The page does not load the correct `page.Vue` Router Looks like not working
but when i write

```
createApp(App).use(router,Antd,VueAxios,axios,qs).mount('#app')
```

it's working!
So why?

code:https://github.com/fangminghui/app_h5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`app.use`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/application-api.html#use) or `createApp(App).use` doesn't accept multiple plugin as parameters, it accepts only the plugin and its options if there's options :

```
createApp(App).use(thePlugin,options)
```

if you want to use multiple ones you should chain multiple `.use` like :

```
createApp(App).use(qs).use(router).use(VueAxios).use(Antd).mount('#app')
```